# How to call another page using Tap Gesture in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uitapgesturerecognizer

I created an Image Button and put a Tap Gesture into it. I want my Image Button to call another Page but I don't know how am I going to do that without using Navigation.PushAsync but it's causing me this error "PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a Navigation Page."

This is my XAML code.

```
<Image Source="add.jpg">
  <Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer

            Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped"
            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

and this is my XAML.CS code.

```
    private void TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped(SecondPage secondPage)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage());

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use `PushAsync`, the parent `Page`  should be a `NavigationPage`.When we use `NavigationPage` and do `PushAsync` the Navigation stack will be maintained and you will get a back button in Actionbar for back navigation.

Rather if we use `PushModalAsync`, the page will be presented modally.

Changing `PushAsync` to `PushModalAsync` will work.

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped(SecondPage secondPage)
{
    Navigation. PushModalAsync(new SecondPage());

}
```

Comment: Sreeraj It Worked. Thank you so much Sir.

Comment: @JayceeEvangelista, I have added the explanation.

Comment: Oh. Now I know. Thank you so much Sir. How can I contact you? I want to ask more question regarding Xamarin.Forms. If it's okay with you Sir. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can perhaps ping me through facebook fb.com/sreerajpr . I will try to help if it is in my scope.

Comment: I just added you Sir.

Comment: Can i ask more question Sir?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for asking questions. You needn't get permission for that :-P . Btw you can call me Sreeraj.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry :D How am i going to create a dropdown that displays different content depending on the selected item? For example, there are 3 items on a dropdown namely Chart1, Chart2 and Chart3. When i choose  Chart1 it should display a Pie Chart. When i choose  Chart2 it should display a Bar Grap. When i choose  Chart3 it should display a Line Graph. Is that possible to do Sreeraj? If yes, How? Thank you.

Comment: You should be asking that as a separate Question. Otherwise it won't receive enough community attention

Comment: Okay Sreeraj wait.

Comment: Sreeraj i'm not allowed to ask more question on this site. It's stated that im  only allowed to ask 2 more days from now.